# Каким образом можно вывести конкретно найденное слово из текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текст, который должен содержать одно или несколько слов. Если это слово содержится, то каким образом вывести какое именно слово нашлось в тексте?

```
banword = ["Поиск","Слова","Дом"]
content = 'Тут будут текст с словами для поиска'
```

Должно вывести какое слово было найдено, в данном случае в тексте есть не все указанные слова.
Проверяю слова вот так.

```
if any(word in content.lower() for word in banword):
  print(f'Найдено совпадение') # Хочу сюда вывести какое/какие слова были найдены
else:
 print(f'Не найдено совпадение')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
banword = ["Поиск","Слова","Дом"]
content = "Тут будет текст со словами для поиска"

###
content_lower = content.lower()
for word in banword:
    if word.lower() in content_lower:
        print(word)
```

Но по хорошему, надо искать не подстроки, а разбираться с регулярными выражениями, потому что: Сабля актера ансамбля из Гренобля. Застрахуй и не психуй.